# graphical representation with (x, y) in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to plot a graph of system differential equation in Matlab.
I am new in this program.
$$ \begin{cases} \dot x=2*x+y    
\\   \dot y=2*(x^2-1)*x \end{cases}$$

This system in nonlinear and functions in Matlab as "quiver" don't help me and there are three equilibrium points.
There are one focus and two saddles. 
I didn't find any useful information in the internet. Thanks for the help.
Sorry for my English!

Comment: Do you intend by "phase portrait" a graphical representation with $(x,\dot x)$ on the axes ?

Comment: @JeanMarie ,  I need a graphical representation with (x, y) on the axes.

Comment: Therefore, it is not the phase space but the ordinary 2D space.

Comment: Thank you, I will correct a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Matlab program that does the job :

> ```
> function main
> clear all;close all,hold on;set(gcf,'color','w');
> axis equal;axis([-2,2,-2,2]);
> set(gcf,'color','w');
> ts = -2:0.01:2; % time range
> s = @(t,V) S(V); % take care : s and S
> for k=-1:0.1:1
>    V0= [0;k]; % column vector : initial point (arbitrarily) chosen on the y-axis  
>    [t,V] = ode45(s, ts, V0);  
>    plot(V(:,1),V(:,2)); 
> end;
> %
> function der = S(x) ; % RHS of the differential system 
> xp1=2*x(1)+ x(2);
> xp2=2*(x(1).^2-1).*x(1);
> der=[xp1;xp2];
> ```

with the result displayed on the figure.

How can we check the obtained curves ? For example, on the curves situated on the right, one sees that the slope is negative, resp. positive for values of $x$ that are $<1$, resp. $>1$. This is easily explainable with the sign of the following expression

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{dy:dt}{dx/dt}=\dfrac{\dot y}{\dot x}=\frac{2(x^2-1)x}{2x+y}$$

The $(x^2-1)$ factor being "entirely responsible" for the change of sign in the area $x>0$ and $y>0$. But a complementary fact brings new light : the change of sign at the boundary given by the transition

If one day, you want to visualize the phase portrait, for example of $x$, i.e. work with generalized coordinates $(x,\dot x)$, plainly

- replace (10 th line) "plot V(:,1),V(:,2)" by "plot V(:,1),2*V(:,1)+V(:,2)" (by reference to equation $\dot x=2x+y$)
- replace V0=[0;k] (8 th line) for example by V0=0.2*(rand(2,1)-0.1.

[image]

Comment: As you have seen, I have taken initial points on $y$ axis now : the understanding of solutions is easier in this way. Does it answers your question ?

Comment: yes, thank you for your answer!

Comment: If this answer is a complete solution for you, think to check it. I have had a look at your profile : you haven't checked any of the answers you have received... some of them a long time ago.

Comment: I always check it by myself or should I  write about it here?

Comment: No, i didn't meant "check = verifying". What I was saying is that on the upper left hand side of answers you have a check sign (looking like a square root sign). Click on it to say you validate this answer as satisfying. This avoids a lot of further answers.

Comment: Otherwise, if you praise a solution but think that there should be coming improved ones, click on the "up" button to increase the "good answer" status.